# Interactive rebase of a branch with its point of divergence from master

Tags: git, rebase

Let's say I have a topic branch whose entire history I want to rewrite since it was originally created from master for a pull request. For whatever reason, it is not easy or obvious using `git log` to determine the commit hash I want to pass to

```
git rebase -i <commit>
```

I know I can use `git merge-base <branch1> <branch2 || master>` to find the commit that two references can trace their ancestry from and can use that to determine the commit. What I would like to know is if there is a better way to interactively rebase this whole branch (whether master has advanced or not) than using

```
git rebase -i `git merge-base my_branch master`
```

EDIT: I do not want to change the parent of the first commit made on this branch so `git rebase -i master` would only work in the case where both master has not advanced since the branch was created and the branch was created from the commit master currently points to.

Comment: This isn't an answer but an interesting hack I came up with. I put the following in my .profile.

`function gri() {
  git rebase -i \`git merge-base $@ master\`
}`

Comment: I could not find anything better, but you can replace `my_branch` by `HEAD`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but I think `git rebase -i master` should do what you want. It will figure out the merge base and rebase the entire branch from that point to the current HEAD so that it appears to have been branched from the current tip of master.

Also, if master has not advanced, then rebasing will pretty much be a no-op.

Comment: Thanks. I realized later that git rebase -i master would do that, but what if I wanted to rebase interactively without changing the head of my branch to be the current head of master in case they weren't already the same.

Comment: If you are on `my-branch` and run `git rebase -i master`, it will only update the `my-branch` ref - it won't update `master`. Rebasing moves the _current_ branch to another point on it's branch parent (or potentially onto a completely different branch parent if you use `--onto`), but doesn't modify any other branches.

Comment: Sorry I guess what I meant was is there a simpler way than what I posted above to rebase a branch to the commit on master that it came from without changing the parent of the first commit of the branch.

Comment: If I'm understanding that right, you want the parent of the first commit on the branch that diverged from the master branch to remain the same, yet still have the effects of any future commits on master included in your branch - i.e. integrating other work on master into your work on your branch? If that's the case, `git merge` is what you want, not `git rebase`. The actual commands would be `git checkout my-branch; git merge master`. `rebase`, by design, is intended for moving commits, changing the shape of the tree.

Comment: Actually, after reading through the whole thing again, maybe you just want to rearrange the commits (possibly skipping some or combining or reordering) on your branch without moving it anywhere? In that case, I think just `git rebase -i` (without specifying a destination branch) should do that.

Comment: Thanks! Your last comment is the interpretation I intended. Any edits you suggest to make my original question more valuable for others? I'll try just `git rebase -i` the next time. I do know for certain that what I posted in the original question works, I just know that merge-base is used internally by git and thought there might be some other way to shorten my expression.

Comment: I think what I missed the first time was that you weren't trying to relocate the branch, but just rearrange it. I personally tend to use `rebase` more for cutting and grafting branches in different places than I do reordering and squashing commits, so I was looking at your question from a different angle. I think making it clear that you're just wanting to tweak the history on an existing branch rather than moving a branch might help, since `git rebase` (and other subcommands as well) sometimes has more than one possible use...

Comment: `git rebase -i` isn't it: this will rebase all changes not in the upstream or something like that, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 5):

I only found one iterative improvement to the command you listed. Your command:

```
git rebase -i `git merge-base my_branch master`
```

An improvement would be to not have to remember the name of the branch you want to rebase. Assuming you're currently on the branch you want to rebase (which is almost always the case in my experience), you could use:

```
git rebase -i `git merge-base HEAD master`
```